# How to put articles to one adjective with multiple nouns

Tags: articles

Suppose that there is a black cup, a black book and a black mouse. How should I put (an) indefinite article(s) to call all of them, while using an adjective *black* only once?

1. A black cup, book and mouse
2. Black a cup, a book and a mouse
3. A black cup, a book and a mouse
4. Work around: a cup, a book and a mouse *that are black*
5. None of them. That is, impossible. That is, A black cup, a black book  and a black mouse

Comment: It depends on how badly you want to stress that they were all black. If that is essential you really need to do as @Centaurus says.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't choose any of the choices given. Number 4 conveys the meaning but I think it would sound more natural to say:

"a cup, a book and a mouse, all of them black."